# Router duplicate on reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router

First I have this piece of code :

```
class navitem extends Component {
    state = {
        isShown: false
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <div href={'#' + this.props.dName} className="navItem">
                        <Link to={"/" + this.props.url}>{this.props.dName}</Link>
                    </div>

                    <Route path={"/textversion"} exact component={TextVersion} />
                </div>
            </Router >
        )
    }
}
```

This works pretty well at the first time, if I click on the button it shows my TextVersion component.
The problem is when I reload the page that component is loaded into each navItem, why is that?

Comment: Your NavItem component shouldn't have the Route and Router, it should be in you Main App Component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri How should I do it then? Add the Router around the component it's in?

Comment: yes, also More info on your App architecture would help in providing a better solution

Comment: I fixed it, added `<Route path="/textversion" component={TextVersion} />` into my navigation bar and then `<Link to={"/" + this.props.url}>{this.props.dName}</Link>` in my navItem

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was first of all the `Router`
It is necessary that you add `Router` around your App like this : 
`ReactDOM.render(<Router><App /></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));`

I added my route above my navigation bar where it should be like this: 
`<Route path="/textversion" component={TextVersion} />`
In my navItem itself I wrote the link to the Route I defined earlier like this : 
`<Link to={"/" + this.props.url}>{this.props.dName}</Link>`